# regular expression ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I need to check if string starts with ROT following range 0-26 and white space....for example my input must be ROT12 "some string" where ROT can be in range ROT0-ROT26... know how to check for ROT with

`input.match /^ROT/`

but need something like this

`input.match /^ROT[0..26] /`

white space behind rot with number is important too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do it brute-force with:

```
 input.match(/\AROT(0|1|2|3|4|...26) /)
```

Or more generally:

```
 input.match(/\AROT(1?[0-9]|2[0123456]) /)
```

Where `\A` is a more specific version of `^` which means "start of string", whereas `^` means "start of line".

Comment: You can also just do `2[0-6]`, don't have to write them all out

Comment: thx for help i used this `input.match(/\AROT([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-6])  /)`

Answer (score 1):

For improved readability consider performing the range test separately.

```
def string_ok?(str)
  str.match?(/\AROT\d+ /) && str[3..-1].to_i <= 26
end

string_ok? "ROT12 "     #=> true
string_ok? "ROT12 cat"  #=> true
string_ok? "ROT "       #=> false
string_ok? "RO0 "       #=> false
string_ok? "ROT0"       #=> false
string_ok? "1ROT0 "     #=> false
string_ok? "ROT27 "     #=> false
string_ok? "ROT-3 "     #=> false
```

Comment: ROT0 must be true

Comment: There's no space following the zero.

Comment: my bad sorry...at first it was like chinese to me now i get your code ...thanks